# How to write Query find Book by Category?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

Suppose I have 2 tables: Book and Category.

- I use Spring Data JPA
- I want to get a list of books by category and view it on Thymeleaf as Category Menu
  ->  how should I write Query?
- below is my way but it has no data

**Book**

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String name;
    
    @Column(length = 100)
    private int isbn;

    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "categoryid")
    private Category category;
```

**Category**

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @NotEmpty(message="Thể loại không được trống")
    private String name;
    
    @NotEmpty(message="Mã không được trống")
    private String code;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
```

**BookRepo**

```java
    @Query(value = "SELECT b.* FROM book b INNER JOIN category c on b.name = c.id WHERE c.id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Book> findBookByCategory(Integer categoryId);
```

**Controller**

```java
    @GetMapping("/{category}")
    public String getBookByProduct(@PathVariable("category") Integer category, Model model, HttpSession session) {
        List<Book> bookList = bookService.findBookByCategory(category);
        
        if(bookList == null) {
            session.setAttribute("message", new MessageResponse("Không có Sách","danger"));
        }
        for(Book book : bookList ) {
            System.out.println(book.toString());
        }
        model.addAttribute("category", bookList);
        return "home/category";
    }
```

**View**

```html
    <h4 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold mb-3">Thể Loại</h4>
                  <div class="mt-2 mb-2 pl-2 ">
                    <div class="custom-control" th:each="category : ${category}" th:value="${category.id}">
                        <h5>
                            <a class="btn btn-info popovers" th:href="@{'/category/' + ${category.id}}"  >[[${category.name}]]</a>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hello this is the approach  I used in my case;
in your repository interface

```
or 
List<Book> findBookByCategoryId(Integer cId);
then in your service class implement the above repo methods 

List<Book> bks= new ArrayList<>();
BookRepo.findBookByCategoryName("programming books")
               .forEach(bks::add);

        System.out.println(bks);

BookRepo.findBookByCategoryId(1)
               .forEach(bks::add);

        System.out.println(bks);
```